# How to set relative paths in Ui - Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have angular application, and all links are relative paths.
We are using Ui-Router.
How can we map a url with multipe "tokens" and still preseve the base URL?

For example:
No matter wether the state url is "/users" or "/users/:id" , I want the relative path to be "/". For "users", the relative path is "/", but for "/users/:id" the relative path is "/users".

I don't want to use absolute path, as it ruin our build.

Here is our config:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/users',
    templateUrl: 'res/users/home.tpl.html'
  }).state('user', {
    url: '/users/:userID',
    templateUrl: 'res/users/user.tpl.html',
    controller: 'viewUserController as ctrl'
  })
```

Trying to access /users, loads all resources from / , while trying to access /users/:userId , load all resources (defined in index.html) from ./users.

Comment: is there any reason that you do not want to use the ui-sref attribute to let your application determine these values for you?

Comment: Ui-sref is a directive. I am talking about configuration. In your suggestion- how should I handle a refresh on a /users/id page?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question.  I am afraid that I still do not grasp what you are asking.  Typically I use nested states when i have a relationship like this between two states.  Would you like to see an example of your snippet configured as nested states?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using nested states might give you the desired effect.  I renamed your first state to users and made the other state a child of it.  I hope this is helpful.  I think that nesting the states like this would establish the relative path relationship between the two states that you are desiring.

```
  .state('users', {
    url: '/users',
    templateUrl: 'res/users/home.tpl.html'
  })
  .state('users.user', {
    url: '/:userID',
    templateUrl: 'res/users/user.tpl.html',
    controller: 'viewUserController as ctrl'
  })
```